# How to refresh Bootstrap modal refresh before modal show

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I was tried to my project many modal but the one modal load the data. After close the modal then I load another modal. But can't load that modal data. That was loaded old modal data. How to solve this problem?

this is my first load Jquery. this data worked properly.

```
function Viewfull(id) {
    $.post('php/owner_list_view_modal.php',{id:id}, function (data) {
        var html = table(data);
         $('.modal-body').html(html);
         $('#orumodal').modal('show');
    });
}

function table(val) {
    var obj = $.parseJSON(val);

        var html = '<style>tr:nth-child(odd){background-color: #f5f5f5;} thead>tr{background-color: #ec971f; color: white;}</style>';
            html += '<table class="table table-bordered has-warning">';
                html += '<tbody>';
                    html += '<tr><td>Name</td><td>'+ obj.name +'</td></tr>';
                    html += '<tr><td>Email</td><td>'+ obj.emailid +'</td></tr>';
                    html += '<tr><td>Mobile</td><td>'+ obj.mobile +'</td></tr>';
                    html += '<tr><td>Address</td><td>'+ obj.address +'</td></tr>';
                    html += '<tr><td>Place</td><td>'+ obj.place +'</td></tr>';
                    html += '<tr><td>City</td><td>'+ obj.city +'</td></tr>';
                    html += '<tr><td>State</td><td>'+ obj.state +'</td></tr>';
                    html += '<tr><td>Pin</td><td>'+ obj.pin +'</td></tr>';
                    html += '<tr><td>Status</td><td>'+ obj.status +'</td></tr>';
                html += '</tbody>';
      return html += '</table>';
}
```

This is my another modal when I clicked first modal data show then closed that modal. Then I click another modal I was shown first modal result:

```
<div id="uploadimg" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="uploadmsg">
               <div class="container">
                   <div class="row well">
                       <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-6">
                           <form method="post" action="profile_image_save.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                               <div class="form-group">
                                   <label>Profile Image</label>
                                   <input type="file" id="profileimg" name="profileimg">
                               </div>
                               <div class="form-group">
                                   <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right">Change</button>
                               </div>
                           </form>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

> you can use something like this to clear old data. Below your code  $('#orumodal').modal('show'); Use any of the following:

```
$("#myModal").val(null).trigger("change");
```

or

```
$('#myModal').removeData();
```

to remove all rows except 1st row:

```
$("#myModal").find("tr:not(:nth-child(1))").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an `event` which is `triggered` before `modal` is shows so you can put your logic of getting data or whatever you want in it.

```
$('#YourModalID').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  //Your code to get data or whatever you want
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/1784/) is jsfiddle

Comment: You can fetch the data and assign to `modal body` in above code.

Comment: This won't refresh the modal, unfortunately.  If you have to set cascading dropdowns inside the modal, refreshing the modal is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Finally this worked for me after adding .show() after reload() . Thanks for all your tips. 
Note : I have added below snippet with in document ready function

```js
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {           
            location.reload();
            $('#myModal').show();
        })
```

Comment: doesn't refresh the modal, simply refreshes the page and the state is lost